# How to check for multiple occurrences of a word using Capybara (or Webrat, I guess) and Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat, capybara

I know that `/Interface \d/` occurs three times on the page. But I don't know how to test for this with Capybara in Cucumber. Here was my first attempt:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see \/([^\/]*)\/ (\d+)(?:x|X| times?)?$/ do |regexp, count|
  regexp = Regexp.new(regexp)
  count = count.to_i
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_xpath('//*', { :text => regexp, :count => count })
  else
    assert page.has_xpath?('//*', { :text => regexp, :count => count })
  end
end
```

However, this returns false for my `Then I should see /Interface \d+/ 3 times`.

I figured out that this is because [`has_xpath`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers%3ahas_xpath%3F) uses [`all`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders%3aall). Putting this in my test:

```
puts all(:xpath, '//*', { :text => regexp}).map {|e| pp e}
```

results in

```
#<Capybara::Element tag="html" path="/html">
#<Capybara::Element tag="body" path="/html/body">
#<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div">
#<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div/div[2]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="table" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table">
#<Capybara::Element tag="tbody" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody">
#<Capybara::Element tag="tr" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="td" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="tr" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="td" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="tr" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]">
#<Capybara::Element tag="td" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]">
```

So I am getting a count of every step along the way to the elements that contain my text. :-\

I thought maybe [`has_content`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers%3ahas_content%3F) would save me, but it doesn't accept a count.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see \/([^\/]*)\/ (\d+)(?:x|X| times?)?$/ do |regexp, count|
  regexp = Regexp.new(regexp)
  count = count.to_i
  page.find(:xpath, '//body').text.split(regexp).length.should == count+1
end
```

Comment: Two reasons I don't like to use "within blah": 1) It's brittle. Right now these are in <td>s, but that will change soon. I don't want to have to change the test. 2) It's not really from a user-perspective, which I like to try to stick to as much as possible in cucumber features.

Comment: Fair enough... I've removed the css selector suggestion.